# undefined index in PHP Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, apache

I'm sure people have come across this issue before but I cannot see where I am going wrong. (I have checked the isset() function in my code and it looks fine, but it's still preventing an email message to be sent)

I have built my custom contact form on Wordpress. So a Form calls a jQuery AJAX function which connects to the PHP file. My PHP file is saved in the root of the Wordpress installation folder (i.e. right at the beginning) Snippet as follows

**jQuery**

```
$('#contactForm').submit(function (event) {
event.preventDefault();  
sendContactForm(); //Call the function
});

function sendContactForm(){
    var dataString=$('#contactForm').serializeArray(); 

    $.post("/contact.php", dataString, function(data) {
    if(data.status == "1") { 
    alert('Message successfully sent');
    }
    else if(data.status=="2") {
    alert('Please enter Antispam correctly');
    } 
    else { 
    alert('Network error. Please try again');
    }
    },
    "json"
    );  

    };
```

**PHP**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json charset=utf-8');
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$choice = $_POST['choice'];     
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'abc@mail.com'; 
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";   
$headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";
$to = 'myname@gmail.com'; 
$subject = $name . ' has sent you a message';
$human = $_POST['antispam'];

$body = "<html><body>";
$body.= "Change Request";
$body.= "<table style='border-color: #666;' cellpadding='2'>";
$body.= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><b>Name:</b> </td><td>" . $name . "</td></tr>";
$body.= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><b>Email:</b> </td><td>" . $email . "</td></tr>";
$body.= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><b>Contact:</b> </td><td>" . $telephone . "</td></tr>";
$body.= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><b>Service Type:</b> </td><td>" . $choice . "</td></tr>";    
$body.= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><b>Message:</b> </td><td>" . $message . "</td></tr>";
$body.= "</table>";
$body.= "</body></html>";   

if( !empty( $_POST['name']) && 
    !empty( $_POST['email']) && 
    !empty( $_POST['telephone']) && 
    !empty( $_POST['choice']) && 
    !empty( $_POST['message']) && 
    $human == '4') {                 
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) { 
        echo '{"status":"1"}';
    } else { 
        echo '{"status":"0"}';
    } 
} 
else 
{
    echo '{"status":"2"}';
}
```

My **error** received in the Network console response is

**Notice**:  Undefined index: name in **/clientdata/apache-www/k/i/mywebsite.com.au/www/contact.php** on line **3**

**Notice**:  Undefined index: email in **/clientdata/apache-www/k/i/mywebsite.com.au/www/contact.php** on line **4**

**Notice**:  Undefined index: telephone in **/clientdata/apache-www/k/i/mywebsite.com.au/www/contact.php** on line **5**
{"status":"2"}

As you can see I have explicitly mentioned that each entry should not be empty and I also enter each of them when I fill up my contact form. It fails for some reason and then goes to the last condition with status = 2. This same code was working before on the same Hosting server. I am not sure is this my code issue or hosting issue which prevents this from being sent.

My **HTML** form as well (not sure if this could help in the investigation as well)

```
<form class="form" role="form" action="#" id="contactForm" name="contactForm" onsubmit="return false;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" required>
    </div>              
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Contact</label>
          <input type="tel" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Request</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="choice">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">Choose...</option>                        
                <option value="Basic Package">Basic</option>
                <option value="Dynamic Request">Advanced</option>                       
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>
    </div>              
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Message</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" name="message"></textarea>
    </div>              
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Anti Spam</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="antispam" placeholder="What is 2+ 2?" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>              
</form>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not showing that you are actually giving the input a name in the HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your missing the name attribute tags. That's why it is not finding any POST data with those indexes.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
      <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" required>
</div>              
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Email</label>
      <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Contact</label>
      <input name="telephone" type="tel" class="form-control" required>
</div>
```

Comment: omg I feel so clumsy! Now I know how it misplaced it. I converted my form to Bootstrap and I overlooked the name tags. Thanks @Andew.

Answer (score 0):

These are causing the Undefined index problems:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$choice = $_POST['choice'];     
$message = $_POST['message'];
```

PHP says that it cannot find 'email' or others in the $_POST array. Change in:

```
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : false;
```

For example or use a function for checking your content.

Comment: And see the answer of @Andrew why it is not finding it ;-)

Comment: I did not specify the name attribute in the HTML. That's why. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try specifing your sites url

```
$.post("<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/contact.php", dataString, function(data) {
```

Since your webservers root may not be your sites root. Also, delete the line

```
header('Content-Type: application/json charset=utf-8');
```

php should be able to read your variables then